# WCF operation to post logs - should it be callback?

Tags: c#, wcf

WCF contains Server and Client side In my case Server is the program that produces data (logs). There are several subscribers that should be notified when a new bunch of data is ready to be posted.

So I think WCF Server should callback some method for all interested clients....

Should I use "CallbackContract" keyword to define one-way callback operation?

I need is `void Log(string)` method which will be called by server for all clients every time something should be possted, how to define such method in terms of WCF?

probably I should avoid "callback" but instead use `string[] getLogs()` method which will return new logs? then client may call `getLogs` method every one or two or three seconds to get logs for the last interval?

Comment: When you say 'for all clients' - which clients do you mean? Those who have called the server so far?

Comment: by clients I mean those programs that should receive data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described looks like Publisher/Subscriber pattern. Check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx

There are also specialized frameworks, like [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) that solve broader problem of asynchronous messaging.

Comment: thanks, this article is a little bit complicated for me. probably I will switch server and clients. Server will receive data and client will attach to server and post data...

Answer (score 1):

what you are asking sounds reasonable, have a look at this one: [WCF Callbacks; a beginners guide](http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-thcggtfw-ww.html)

Comment: The above link is now dead

Comment: @d219 link is fixed now