# my first WCF Server - why OperationContext.Current is null?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm tring to implement my first WCF call-back server. This is my code:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(ILogCallback))]
public interface ILog
{
}

public interface ILogCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Push(string callbackValue);
}

public class MyLog : ILog
{

}

class Log
{


    public static void initialize()
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
            typeof (MyLog),
            new Uri[]
                {
                    new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
                }))
        {

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (ILog),
                                    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                                    "PipeReverse");

            host.Open();
            // TODO: host.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void Push(string s)
    {
        ILogCallback callbacks = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ILogCallback>();
        callbacks.Push(s);
    }
}
```

then I try to use my server using this code:

```
        Log.initialize();

        while (true)
        {
            Log.Push("Hello");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

But I got NPE, because OperationContext.Current is null. Why, what's wrong and how to fix that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you are NOT in the context of an operation.

You're simply calling a static method of the Log class.

For you to be in an Operation Context your call MUST have been come from a client that is being serviced by your WCF server.

Comment: But note I don't want client to call any Server methods. I want Server to call `Log.Push` on Clients. That's why I used "callback" method...

Comment: @javapowered, That basically means that you want your client to be a server. Use plain simplex communication, no need for callbacks.

Comment: hm what is "plain simplex communication"? You think I should not use WCF? I just need to propogate logs from one server to several clients, note my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370423/wcf-operation-to-post-logs-should-it-be-callback

Comment: Use a simpler message exchange pattern. Just set up a service (on your 'client') that will respond to Push calls. Don't use dual bindings and callback contracts.

Comment: I responded to your original question. I really think you are going the wrong way.

Comment: @javapowered the CallbackContract requires duplex channel, i.e. a channel that is actively used by both parties. Duplex sounds about right for your needs, but it requires that your clients first connects to your server and provides the callback. Keep in mind that for http bindings the communication needs to happen within a session, and for net.tpc you can simply keep the connection open. So add a Connect method on your service, and have the client call that, providing its implementation of the callback. Then keep the session/channel open until the client is no longer interested in log messages

Answer (score 1):

`OperationContext.Current` is a thread-static property that is initialized when request arrives to the server. Here's what you do to call the callback

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(ILogCallback))]
public interface ILog
{
  void PushOnTheClient();
}

public class MyLog : ILog
{
  void PushOnTheClient()
  {
        ILogCallback callbacks = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ILogCallback>();
        callbacks.Push(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: who should call `PushOnTheClient` method? I don't need clients to call any server methods. I need server to call clients methods. Server should post logs to clients

Comment: That means you need to reverse the roles. The one who chooses when and what to call is the client.

Comment: Then I will have one client (that produces logs) and several servers (that should receive logs). Every time new server is added I will need to modify client to attach to new server. This is very odd, I need typical "subscribers" pattern.... I don't want to modify the part that produces logs every time I attach or detach the part that listen for the logs

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370423/wcf-operation-to-post-logs-should-it-be-callback/7373831#7373831

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the subscriber's subscription. The way you do this is to create a [oneway] operation in your MyLog WCF server called something like: "`void SendMeLogs()`". 
This will open the client callback channel. You Then have to implement `SendMeLogs()` in lines of something like:

```cs
void SendMeLogs()
{
  while(CheckLogsForNewData())
 {
   PushOnTheClient();
 }
}
```

Since the `SendMeLogs()` function is oneway, the client will not block, but will start the subscription to your log server. (you can search the net for sample code for duplex calculator in wcf for a good example of this architecture).
 The key however is that you must have a nice unsubscribe method like "`StopSendingMeLogs`" to break the loop, and also make the `PushOnTheClient` function fail safe, in case the client terminates or the specific client connection goes down.
 The "`CheckLogsForNewData`" function should ideally be a shared (static) implementation in your case